# Property 'find' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

I am running into this type error with the .find method. I know this is a tsconfig.json lib issue but I read every single article and none of the solutions worked for me.

I tried adding to the lib list: es5, es2015, es6, es2016, es7, es2017, es2018, es2019, etc. one by one.
I also tried adding all those to the target as well

My typescript version is 4.9.4

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
  {...}
```

This is what's giving me the TS error:

```
const favoritedReview = user?.favoriteReviews?.find(
  ({ _id }: any) => _id === review._id
)
```

[code showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiUoP.png)

This is the interface props:

```
user?: {
    _id: string
    username: string
    favoriteReviews: object
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you share the TypeScript code that is showing this error? I might be able to help you then as I have solved this error in the past: https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS2339

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. If I declare `favoriteReviews` as `any` on the interface props then it goes away but I'm wondering if I can solve it by leaving it as object. If not, then I'll do `any`

Comment: Don't use `object`. Specify the type.

Comment: Show the error you are getting

Comment: @rschristian how can I specify the type of `.find()`?

Comment: `favouriteReviews` is typed as an object but`find` is an array method.

Comment: @SavedCity are you sure that `favoriteReviews` is an `object` and not an `Array`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Where is - favoriteReviews - defined?

Comment: @SavedCity `object` means any non-primitive value. It's basically a deprecated part of TypeScript and should be avoided as it provides no (useful) type information beyond vaguely narrowing it down. `.find()` is an array method, so you should specify as such.

Comment: ya'll right! I declared it as object without thinking way before getting this error. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is part of the `Array.prototype`, so your `favoriteReviews` might be an array:

```
interface UserInterface {
  _id: string;
  username: string;
  favoriteReviews: {
    _id: number
  }[];
}

function test(user: UserInterface, review: { _id: number }) {
  const favoritedReview = user?.favoriteReviews?.find(
    ({_id}) => _id === review._id
  );
  console.log(favoritedReview);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I overthought the error.

Comment: Happy to help! I also have a website explaining common TypeScript errors if you're interested: https://typescript.tv/errors/

Comment: Sweet. Definitely checking it out!